# React app scrolling issue - need to scroll twice to activate scrolling?

Tags: css, reactjs

I don't know why, but my site does not scroll the first time I try to scroll - I need to scroll twice to make it scroll vertically? And if I stop/pause at any point on the page, I need to scroll twice again to activate scroll? I cannot see what's wrong? If I remove the last two sections (footer and the section above, it works?).

http://www.unity-cards.com

Any help is REALLY appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: you have two vertical scrollbars

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Due to two vertical scrollbar, it is happening. First scrollbar is scrolling in first action and then on second scroll actual browser scroll is happening. If you remove internal vertical scrollbar, it will work as you expect.

Comment: THANK you sooo much - I've perhaps been struggling with this for too long (all night) and obviously have missed this.